# How do you convert YYYY_MM to date in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, date, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a column which has dates as texts. Like: '2021_01' (I will reefer this column as TextDate)

I convert it to '2021-01' with this code:
`SELECT REPLACE(at.TextDate,'_','-') as DataFormat FROM tableName at`

But when I try to cast it to date, or convert it to date, I always get 'Missing expression' errors. I tried this:

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), at.TextDate, 126, '_', '-') as date FROM tableName at
```

But it will give me errors. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`convert` means something completely different](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CONVERT.html#GUID-C8BA0657-61C8-4964-A4CB-9292390853F6) in Oracle than it does elsewhere. You need the [`to_date()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/TO_DATE.html#GUID-D226FA7C-F7AD-41A0-BB1D-BD8EF9440118):

```
SELECT TO_DATE(at.textDate, 'YYYY_MM') as DataFormat FROM tableName at
```

If you want to display it in a particular format then you can either let your client/application do that - most clients by default will use your session's `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` setting - or explicitly convert it back to a string with the complementary [`to_char()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/TO_CHAR-datetime.html#GUID-0C3EEFD1-AE3D-452D-BF23-2FC95664E78F).

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c8f93b7f445d9b454d1d45ab5cf7468d)

The valid date elements are also [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-49B32A81-0904-433E-B7FE-51606672183A). You should only convert to a string for display though; while you are manipulating or storing it you should treat it as a date.

---

> How can I filter last 3 months with it?

You need to use Oracle syntax, not SQL Server or other syntax. You also can't refer to a column alias in the same level of query. SO you can recalculate the date value; or as your string format is relatively sane you can convert the target date to a string and compare that, which might allow an index to be used. Something like:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(at.textDate, 'YYYY_MM') as DataFormat
FROM tableName at
WHERE at.textDate >= TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), -3), 'YYYY_MM')
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6bde8cb3f0d8bef158f7c61cfba85b8f)

Answer (score 1):

`TO_DATE` with appropriate format mask.

Just to know what's what:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.
```

Code:

```
SQL> select to_date('2021-01', 'yyyy_mm') from dual;

TO_DATE('2021-01','
-------------------
01.01.2021 00:00:00

SQL>
```